# Get Gridview Datakey from nested gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a gridview nested inside another gridview. What I need is that on the inner gridview get the DataKey from the outer gridview.
How can I pass it?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvPeople" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="Grid" DataKeyNames="person_id" OnRowDataBound="gvPeople_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="10px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <img alt = "" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/glyphicons/png/glyphicons_236_zoom_in.png" />
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                            <asp:GridView ID="gvDocuments" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass = "ChildGrid" DataKeyNames="document_id" ShowFooter="true" 
                                OnRowCommand="gvDocuments_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="gvDocuments_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleted="gvDocuments_RowDeleted" OnRowDeleting="gvDocuments_RowDeleting"
                                GridLines="Horizontal" >
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="document_date" HeaderText="Document Date"  />
                                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="100px" DataField="value" HeaderText="Value" DataFormatString="{0:#,##.00 €}" />
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="delbutton" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("document_id") %>' CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
                                            &nbsp;
                                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="editbutton" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("document_id") %>' Text="Edit" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="newdoc" CommandName="New" Text="New Document" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
                                        </FooterTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="ndocs" HeaderText="Nº of Documents" />
                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="total_cost" HeaderText="Total Cost" DataFormatString="{0:#,#0.00 €}" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Here is my aspx code, which is all working, with the excpetion of the new document button, which runs a javascript button, as the edit button, but on this one I need to pass the person_id, from the row of the gvPeople, so when I create a new gvDocuments row, it will make it to that person id.

Thanks.

Comment: where is relevant code?

Answer (score 1):

Just put it to work.

Add a hiddenfield before the child gridview with the value that I want.
On the RowDataBound of the child gridview, added this:

```
string str= ((HiddenField)e.Row.Parent.Parent.Parent.FindControl("hf")).Value.ToString();
```

And now use the str value for anything that I want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first access each of the parent gridview row then access the child gridview row then access the datakey.

Example:

```
foreach (GridViewRow rowPeople in gvPeople.Rows)
{
    GridView gvDocuments = (GridView)rowPeople.FindControl("gvDocuments");
    //this will get you the outer/parent gridview datakeys
    gvDocuments.DataKeys[rowPeople.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString();
    foreach (GridViewRow rowDocuments in gvDocuments.Rows)
    {
        //this will get you the inner/child gridview datakeys
        gvDocuments.DataKeys[rowDocuments.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString();
    }
}
```

Let me know if that works for you!